# How to remove unneeded permissions on Ionic 5 capacitor Android app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am setting up my first Ionic React app.  I created an app with Ionic 5 and used the [In-app Purchase 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) plugin.

I wanted to test this, so I uploaded the signed APK to the Play Store.

When I check the app bundle details on the Play Store, I see that it requires several unneeded permissions:

> **Required permissions (13)**

> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
> android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA,
> android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
> android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED,
> android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
> com.android.vending.BILLING,
> com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

For example, it doesn't need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, RECORD_AUDIO, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and so on.

I didn't set any of this up; apparently "[Capacitor apps ship with all the core plugins included](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/852#issuecomment-506312993)."

How do I remove these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions are stored in `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.  You can delete them and then rebuild the app to remove them.

Comment: Also, you can explicitly add those permissions in that file with attribute `tools:node="remove"`. For ex. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cordova, and the plugin fileOpener2 uses the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, however it isn't necessary in my app context.

so I had do write a hack, that removes this line from /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml just after the command cordova prepare.

Those commands are located in a build.sh that I use to generate the app version targeting each environment.

```
sed '/REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES/d' platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml > platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest_new.xml 
rm -rf platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
mv platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest_new.xml platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

hope it helps you!